# Почему callback_query выдает ошибку при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, aiogram

код где создается кнопка

```
@dp.message_handler(text='Профиль')
async def profile_user(message: types.Message):
    info_user = {
        'Username': message.from_user.username,
        'first name': message.from_user.first_name,
        'ID user': message.from_user.id,
        'Primary': 'NO',
    }
    full_info = f"<b>User name</b>: {info_user['Username']}\n" \
                f"<b>First name</b>: {info_user['first name']}\n" \
                f"<b>ID</b>: {info_user['ID user']}\n" \
                f"<b>Prime</b>: {info_user['Primary']}"
    inlineKEYBOD = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    button_inl = [types.InlineKeyboardButton('Пополнить баланс', callback_data='q1'), types.InlineKeyboardButton('Купить Прайм', callback_data='q2'),
                  types.InlineKeyboardButton('История покупок', callback_data='q3'), types.InlineKeyboardButton('История пополнений', callback_data='q4')]
    inlineKEYBOD.add(button_inl[0], button_inl[1])
    inlineKEYBOD.add(button_inl[2], button_inl[3])
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                           full_info,
                           reply_markup=inlineKEYBOD,
                           parse_mode='html')
```

код где начинается обработка

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def handlers_call(call: types.CallbackQuery):
        if call.data == 'q1':
        await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, text="<b>Выберите способ оплаты</b>", reply_markup=payment_acceptance, parse_mode='html')
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse inline keyboard button: text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard